# making djangocms url resolvers less greeady

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I have a high traffic django-cms site. On the same site there is a also an additional django app with a restful api.
I have following urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap',
        {'sitemaps': {'cmspages': CMSSitemap}}),
    url(r'^taggit_autosuggest/', include('taggit_autosuggest.urls')),
    url(r'^select2/', include('django_select2.urls')),
    url(r'^api/', include('api.urls')),
]

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(    
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
)
```

The issue is that if the api returns a 404 at application level for one its urls (e.g for `/api/post/15`), the last line in the `urls.py` definitions intercepts the 404, and returns a 302, making a redirect to `/en/api/post/15` (supposing English is the default language).

This behaviour is fine for all CMS URIs, but not for the API, where it just increases the traffic. How can I avoid that the django-cms url does not intercept the 404 from the API.

Answer (score 0):

this might actually be a Django bug. django CMS does not intercept 404s, if a 404 is raised at the application level then django's locale middleware will catch it and do the redirect. I believe this to be a bug since it either shouldn't intercept explicit application 404s or in the middleware it should use the resolver match from the request to see if the pattern that matched is an i18n one.